# Microsoft Graph API - search on multiple email addresses?

Tags: php, curl, microsoft-graph-api

I’m trying to query the Graph API to return me mail messages that are from OR to a particular email address by using the “participants” search term.

Docs here; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters

Code example (working):

```
$encoded_addresses = urlencode("participants:email@domain.com");
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="' . $encoded_addresses . '"'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"', 'Accept: application/json','Authorization: Bearer '.$account['access_token']));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($response);
```

One email address (above example) works. But if I pass in more than one email address to the participants parameter, it fails and I get ALL messages in the mailbox retrieved regardless of participants.

Code example (not working):

```
$encoded_addresses = urlencode("participants:email@domain.com or anotheremail@anotherdomain.com");
    $url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="' . $encoded_addresses . '"'; 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Prefer: outlook.body-content-type="text"', 'Accept: application/json','Authorization: Bearer '.$account['access_token']));
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($response);
```

I’m using PHP and cURL.

Has anyone managed to search on multiple values? If so with what syntax?

Note I’m using search and not filter parameter.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide the query you've made?

Comment: Sure, have just added working and non working code above, many thanks

Comment: This request works for me and I think it's identical to yours: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="participants%3Aemail%40domain.com+or+anotheremail%40anotherdomain.com"

Comment: Are you testing it directly in the Graph Explorer or within your own code?

Comment: @Satya V - So I tried this but it didn't work. If I pass ONE email address it returns the messages correctly. If I pass TWO email addresses (as per your code example) it returns ALL the messages in the mailbox and not just those where the two email addresses are participants! It would seem that the presence of the or operator breaks the query??

Comment: @andrewgt It was tested in Graph Explorer. Could you please share details of the request created by curl? Maybe the url in the request will be different from what we expect.

Comment: Here's the full (encoded) URL generated for the cURL request, below. Note if I just use ONE participant then it works fine. If I use two it fails and returns me every message in the mailbox. I can recreate this behaviour in the Graph Explorer too...  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=%22participants%3Asimon%40bbc.co.uk%22+or+%22participants%3Abob%40bbc.co.uk%22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment your request url is this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="participants:simon@bbc.co.uk" or "participants:bob@bbc.co.uk"
```

Which is wrong. The correct forms should be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="participants:simon@bbc.co.uk or participants:bob@bbc.co.uk"
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="participants:simon@bbc.co.uk or bob@bbc.co.uk"
```

Try to use `curl_escape` instead of `urlencode`

```
$ch = curl_init();
$query =  curl_escape($curl ,'participants:email@domain.com or anotheremail@anotherdomain.com');
$url = 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="' . $query . '"';
```

Comment: You, my friend, have nailed it. Works perfectly. Thank you ever so much.

Comment: @andrewgt If it solved your problem you can mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

For the OR condition, you could use the below way   :

```
"participants: email@domain.com  or participants:anotheremail@anotherdomain.com"
```

Modification of your code will be as below :

```
$encoded_addresses = urlencode("participants: email@domain.com  or participants:anotheremail@anotherdomain.com");
```

Comment: I tried to mention you in a comment above but it may not have worked. Code change failed sadly.